# How to do scan document index

Tags: installation

I want to index bulk scanning documents 
I have 2 type of document as invoice and bills 
I want to upload this different type of document to 2 separate folder
can you please help me how to achieve this problem

Comment: can you add the code which you have already tried?

Comment: I do not see the relevance to programming. please clarify your issue, and read [ask]